# Matching a text in webpage content but thorws out of index error

Tags: python, regex, wget, urllib

This code throws error index out of range error

```
import os
import re

url = "http://www.jabong.com/purys-Beige-Shirts-1059637.html"
wget_data = os.popen('wget -qO- %s'% url).read()
data = re.findall(r'c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold">(.*)<\/table',wget_data)[0]
print data
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "variable_concat.py", line 7, in <module>
    images = re.findall(r'c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold">(.*)<\/table',wget_data)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is a big string from webpage content how could i match it?

```
r'c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold">(.*)<\/table'
```

Comment: you can use `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()` to load an html in python

Comment: This is because `data` is empty list. Your regex matches nothing. And I don't think you really want to use *regex* to **parse** *html*. You don't want to go there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup parser.

```
import os
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.jabong.com/purys-Beige-Shirts-1059637.html"
wget_data = os.popen('wget -qO- %s'% url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(wget_data)
print soup.find('table', class_="c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold").contents
```

If you really want to use regex then you need to enable DOTALL modifier. Because `.` by default won't match  line breaks(`\n` or `\r`).

```
import os
import re

url = "http://www.jabong.com/purys-Beige-Shirts-1059637.html"
wget_data = os.popen('wget -qO- %s'% url).read()
data = re.findall(r'(?s)c999 fs12 mt10 f-bold">(.*?)<\/table',wget_data)[0]
print data
```

Comment: what is this (?s) doing here?

Comment: You could enable the DOTALL modifier within the regex itself by putting `(?s)` at the start. OR you could set the flag as parameter like `re.DOTALL`